# Django: get drop-down values for a FormField

Tags: html, django, django-models, jquery-select2, modelform

Aim is to get the drop-down to work.

Normally no problems when feeding the whole Model / ModelForm into the html template as `{{ form }}`

Below html code snippet is my aim, but instead of `{{ form }}`, I would like to feed the subset `{{ form.car_model_make }}` and let Django automatically create all Options `<option value="BWM">BMW</option>` ... etc

```
# models.py
class Product(models.Models):
    car_model_make = models.CharField(default='B', max_length=1, blank=True, choices=CAR_TYPE)
    status_is_secondhand = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

# forms.py
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('__all__')

# views.py
class ProductFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('product/', ProductFormView.as_view(template_name='product/product.html'), name='product'),
]
```

The choices CAR_TYPE is a list containing "BMW, Mercedes, Audi".

Trying to achieve this:

When I replace:

```
  <option value="BWM">BWM</option>
  <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
```

in the HTML code snippet below
with

```
{{ form.car_model_make }}
```

I get "No results found"

with

```
<option> {{ form.car_model_make }} </option>
```

I get a list of the choices (BMW, Mercedes, Audi) but they are not selectable

However, with

```
    <option {{ form.car_model_make }} </option>
```

It works but I get a warning Tag start is not closed. If I close the Tag, I get the tag character ">" also printed in the drop down.

same result is produced for: `<option value=" {{ form.car_model_make }} "></option>`

I am in the dark and the trial and error does not give me the desired solution. How do I do it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="col-sm-12 mg-t-10 mg-sm-t-0">
    <select class="form-control select2"
            style="width: 100%;"
            data-placeholder="Choose Car Make"
            >
      <option value="BWM">BWM</option>
      <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="Audi">Audi</option>

    </select>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please include your `forms.py` file

Comment: updated with views, forms, urls, models

Comment: instead of replacing the options, replace the entire select with `{{ form.car_model_make }}`

Comment: Thanks, only caveat is that I loose formatting, default drop-downs aren't pretty. Best for design if I could stick to one type of formatting, such as Select2 or Crispy

Comment: You can override the widget in order to set class and placeholder https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Much appreciated, looks like an answer, I quickly tested it seems to be a solution when install Django-Select2 (Widgets), but need to spend more time to get it pretty. If you bother to write a full example, I can mark it as answer, else, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are two steps to get what you are looking for.

1. Get the select to show up:

instead of replacing the options, replace the entire select with `{{ form.car_model_make }}`

2. Custom formatting for the widget:

Following Django's ModelForm [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) you can override the widget to customize the look and feel, something similar to the following:

```
    widgets = {
        'car_model_make': Select(attrs={
            'class':"form-control select2",
            'style':"width: 100%;",
            'data-placeholder':"Choose Car Make"}),
    }
```